# Will this MOSFET be on under these conditions?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, heater

I'm designing a circuit to control power going to a heater. I'll be using [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/on-semiconductor/NTD4815N-35G/1484786?s=N4IgTCBcDaIHYBcAmAWAHARgKxwLQGYsBzEAXQF8g) n-channel mosfet. My intended voltage values are:

1 is at 24 VDC for both circuits.

I want the mosfet to be on when 3 = 3.3V and off when 3 = 0 V.

I'm still pretty new to mosfets and want to make sure this will work before ordering the parts. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: You need p-mosfet or place that n-mosfet to low side.

Comment: that won't work until you swap the heater and fets in the diagram. In fact, that could blow the FETs as (24v - 3.3v) > 20V max VGS in the datasheet.

Comment: I see, I switch the mosfets and the heater so the source is connected to ground. So then when I apply 3.3V to the gate, Vgth will be 3.3V and turn on. Then when I put 0V to the gate the Vgth will be 0V and it'll turn off? Is that right?

Comment: Wrong. It's supposed to be Vgs, not Vgth. So voltage between gate and source.